# SP2013 add IE9 gradient support

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, css, branding

I am working on branding SP2013 and everything is working except for IE9 support the gradient. I tried adding in,

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .gradient {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

but it did not fix the issue and SP2013 dev console did not like the syntax. Is there a way to do this or should I just do it via an image tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK IE9 has dropped support for `filter` and moved on to use `-ms-filter` which itself has been dropped in IE10 ;-)

Basically, to make things work in IE8/9 use:

```
filter: alpha(opacity=40);
-ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=40)";
```

And in IE10+ we can finally use the CSS standard `opacity` property :-)

For more info, see also:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900647/ms-filter-vs-filter-whats-the-difference
and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

As for CSS3 gradients, IE9 does not support them and you need to use an SVG workaround as seen here:
https://ie.microsoft.com/TESTDRIVE/Graphics/SVGGradientBackgroundMaker/Default.html

IE10 finally has support for CSS3 gradients as per W3C standard.